# C# Task program unable to add new items in Windows Form App

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm taking a rubbish C# course online, and it wants me to create a program that is like a chore list that the user can use add, remove, or clear items on the list.

The problem I am having is when I add text to the textbox and then click a button(say Add front) nothing happens.

Here are some code snippet and a pic:

[image: Image showing windows form designer]

```
LinkedList<string> todoList = new LinkedList<string>();


public void DisplayList()
{
    ItemTextBox.Text = ""; //this is the very top box.
    ToDoListBox.Text = "";

    foreach(string MyString in todoList)
    {
        ToDoListBox.Text += MyString;
    }
}

private void AddFrontButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerator iterator = todoList.GetEnumerator();

    //If the user desides to add the task to the front of the list.
    if(ItemTextBox.Text != "")
    {
        todoList.AddFirst(ItemTextBox.Text);
        DisplayList();
    }
}
```

And here are some Instructions from the course:

> Add the following code within your class:
>
> Declare a LinkedList variable containing string data, named todoList.
>   Create a method called DisplayList(), which does the following:
>   Clear the contents of the ItemTextBox and the ToDoListBox.
>   Use a foreach loop to walk each string in the todoList.
>   Inside the loop, add the current string from todoList to the ToDoListBox
>   Create event handler function for the AddFrontButton and add the following logic:
>
> If there is any text in the ItemTextBox add the text to the front of the todoList
>   Call the DisplayList() function to refresh the ToDoListBox on the screen

Comment: Can you post your method DisplayList(); I think the issue you have is related to the if statement and then the call to the method.

Comment: @Matthew Kaulfers  It's the first method after the `LinkedList<string>` declaration. Let the OP know that his `ToDoListBox` seem to be a `ListBox` control, not a `TextBox`. Should be the reason why they insist on a `LinkedList` as the tool of choice.

Comment: @Matthew Kaulfers I did post the DisplayList() method, I posted it near the top of my code :)

Comment: @Jimi Here is some more  Instructions from the course: https://imgur.com/a/y3OeYMe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For sure your code will not do what you intend to do. There are many things wrong with it. I haven't tested it, but here is what the code should roughly look like:

```
LinkedList<string> todoList = new LinkedList<string>();


public void DisplayList()
{
    ItemTextBox.Text = ""; //this is the very top box.
    ToDoListBox.Items.Clear();

    foreach(string MyString in todoList)
    {
        ToDoListBox.Items.Add(MyString);
    }
}

private void AddFrontButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Collections.IEnumerator iterator = todoList.GetEnumerator();

    //If the user desides to add the task to the front of the list.
    if(!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ItemTextBox.Text))
    {
        todoList.AddFirst(ItemTextBox.Text);
        DisplayList();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! But the statement     ToDoListBox.Items.Add(new ListBoxItem(MyString)); doesn't work, however the statement 
    ToDoListBox.Items.Add(MyString); does work. May I ask why you added the new ListBoxItem in your code?

Comment: As mentioned, I didn't test the code and was writing it from memory. Been a very long time that haven't developed WinForms apps. In most other frameworks (e.g. WPF, UWA, etc.) ListBox.Items is a collection of ListBoxItem objects or something similar. In this case it's simply receiving a string, so should be fine.